# how to click driver find_element_by_xpath - not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="primefacesmessagedlg" class="ui-message-dialog ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="primefacesmessagedlg_title" aria-hidden="false" style="width: auto; height: auto; left: 256.5px; top: 255px; z-index: 1001; display: block;" aria-live="polite">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top ui-draggable-handle">

      <span class="ui-dialog-title">Alert!!</span>

      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
      </a>
   </div>
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="height: auto;"><span class="ui-dialog-message ui-messages-info-icon"></span>OTP has been generated and sent to registered Mobile No:XXXXXX0002 with reference number 891</div>
</div>
```

How to click on this X icon using selenium python code

```
<div id="primefacesmessagedlg" class="ui-message-dialog ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="primefacesmessagedlg_title" aria-hidden="false" style="width: auto; height: auto; left: 256.5px; top: 255px; z-index: 1001; display: block;" aria-live="polite"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top ui-draggable-handle"><span class="ui-dialog-title">Alert!!</span><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span></a></div><div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="height: auto;"><span class="ui-dialog-message ui-messages-info-icon"></span>reference number 891</div></div>
```

I tried with this code but I got error

```
 Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: you may try this: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'ui-icon-closethick')]")`. If this doesn't work, then I am afraid you need to post more html code to traverse to the element, or share the website link if you may.

Comment: @AnandGautam I trird with this but getting error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I will update HTML code Can you please check .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all"]').click()
```

you have used "Click" method, it won't return anything.

Just use this `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all"]').click()`

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay 
not working for my code. may be I was wrong can you please take a look of my code 

<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top ui-draggable-handle"><span class="ui-dialog-title">Alert!!</span><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span></a></div>

here only showing X on this alert and not able to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add waiting

```
button = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.dismiss')))
button.click()
```

Or try to use js click

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all"]')

def js_click(self, element):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```